# using ldapsearch to return only a value

Tags: linux, openldap

using an **OPENLDAP** server i want to retrieve informations from it with **ldapsearch**. I created a custom class called **iduriclass**, this class is used to store an id and an uri. in my ldapsearch command i want it to return only the uri for a specified id.

**EXAMPLE :** the directory contain now two entries `id=test uri=server.com/test` and `id=test2 uri=server.com/test2`

Trying it i get an **ldif** file that contains all uris in the server

I want to have an ldapsearch command that takes test as argument and returns only a value that is : `server.com/test`

Comment: Why not add your query string and the actual ldapsearch command used into your question?

Comment: Can you show me how please :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's how you query your ldap server.

```
HOSTNAME=<your ladap hostname>
USERNAME=<your ldap username>
PASSWORD=<your ldap username's password>
SEARCHBASE=<your ldap's search base DN>
QUERYSTRING=test1
PORT=<your ldap port>

ldapsearch -LLL -h ${HOSTNAME} -p $PORT -D cn=${USERNAME} -w ${PASSWORD} -b "${SEARCHBASE}" "(id=${QUERYSTRING})" uri | sed -n 's/^[ \t]*uri:[ \t]*\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

The option `-LLL` will not print ldap comments on output. Your ldap may require `-x` (simple authentication) if it doesn't support `SASL`.

Comment: i did this and the result was:
dn: id=test,dc=example,dc=com
uri: server.com/test/file

i want it to output only : server.com/test/file

Comment: Check my edit. ldapsearch will always return the dn: so piping to sed and removing it and the attribute name uri: leaves only the attribute value.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671354/7715759) from badc0de spares you the parsing and is additionally working with multiple line attributes (as sshpupkeys might have)

Answer (score 5):

Adding the parameter **-tt** writes a file with ONLY the requested attribute(s) value as the OP requested. No preceding field name or anything else. Path is configurable with **-T**, otherwise is `/tmp`

Comment: `-t[t]  A  single -t writes retrieved non-printable values to a set of temporary files.  This is useful for dealing with values containing non-character data such as jpegPhoto or audio. A second -t writes all re‐trieved values to files.`

Comment: `-T path   Write temporary files to directory specified by path (default: /var/tmp/)`